# Retain latin accent characters C++ ISO-8859-1

Tags: c++

A C++ program sends the following as an email subject with the following text:

> Adjuntamos información existente en nuestra base de datos.
>   Si el informe llegase en blanco, quiere decir que no ha tenido ninguna incidencia en el periodo indicado o no figura información. Si desea responder a este correo, por favor, hágalo a

The encoding is set to ISO-8859-1. The text is getting sent to the email recipient as:

> Adjuntamos informaciÃ³n existente en nuestra base de datos.
>   Si el informe llegase en blanco, quiere decir que no ha tenido ninguna incidencia en el periodo indicado o no figura informaciÃ³n. Si desea responder a este correo, por favor, hÃ¡galo a

What do I need set my encoding to have the accent characters remain as inputed?

Comment: The second sample is typical of UTF-8 interpreted as Latin1. (I.e. you're not sending ISO-8859-1).

Comment: How is it being sent?  If you're outputting to an `ostream`, you'll have to see what the locale is.  Then you'll have to see what your mail server might be doing.

Comment: When this read from the TCP buffer, even prior to sending the email, the accent characters have already changed:

Comment: // Receive parameters from client
 m_cTCP.SetupForRecordsetRead( 0 );

 m_cTCP.Receive( 0, "sssssiisiidisiisib",
     &csOutputDevCode,   // A250, NTAP, FAX, ...
     &csExtServiceCodeProvider, // TAP
     &csOutputPeriph,
     &csTo,
     &csScript,
     &ciSerialNo,
     &ciAlarmNo,
     &csEvName,
     &ciLogSeqNo,
     &ciEventNo,
     &cdEvDate,
     &ciSessionNo,
     &csOperatorWorkstation,
     &ciWorkstationGroup,
     &ciUserGroup,
     &csUserId,
     &ciAttachLSeqNo,
     &m_cbValidation );

Comment: You have to encode non-ASCII characters in the subject according to RFC-2047. Take a look at [Encoded-Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) in Wikipedia.

Comment: For non-ASCII data encoding is used: the MIME specification lists two binary-to-text encoding schemes quoted-printable for text and base64 for binary attachments.

Comment: Where would I need to set this MIME specification?

Comment: Read the RFCs, manuals and Google for open source C++ implementation of SMTP.

Comment: This is to read first *MIME - Content-Transfer-Encoding* - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding

Comment: Thanks for the help on this everyone. I read through the RCF's and have a much better understanding of this issue now. I was able to resolve this by changing the m_sCharset type to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-1 in the following function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CPJNSMTPBodyPart::CPJNSMTPBodyPart() : m_sCharset(_T("UTF-8")), 
                                   m_sContentType(_T("text/plain")), 
                                   m_pParentBodyPart(NULL), 
                                   m_bAttachment(FALSE),
                                   m_pszRawBody(NULL),
                                   m_ContentTransferEncoding(NO_ENCODING)
{
  //Automatically generate a unique boundary separator for this body part by creating a guid
   m_sBoundary = CreateGUID();
}
```